# If I file a patent in America, will forign companies be completely invulnerable to my patent?

Tags: international

The title pretty much says it all. If I file a patent in the US, will forign companies be able to use it without fear?

Comment: related: http://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/12432/jurisdiction-of-a-us-patent

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, yes.  You may have some options if the competitor's product is imported or if the invention is a process used to make a product that finds its way to the US.

Patents are specific to the country in which they are issued.

Answer (score 0):

Technically it is not the **company** being foreign that is the issue, it is where the activity occurs. So IBM can make your US patented thing in the UK and sell it in China - if we are talking about a patented thing.